# Translating data with xml

Tags: xml

I have a small data about some movies as an example

title:The matrix

year: 1999

directors: Andy and Lana Watchowski

writers:Andy and Lana Watchowski

stars: Keanu reeves, carrie fisher

title: star wars

year: 1977

director: George Lucas

writer: George Lucas

stars: mark Hamill, harrison ford

how to translate this into xml??

Comment: Is this correct?

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<movies>
    <title>The Matrix</title>
    <year>1999</year>
    <director>Andy and Lana Watchowski</director>
    <writer>Andy and Lana Watchowski</writer>
    <stars>Keanu reeves, carrie fisher</stars>
</movies> 

how the second movie is added to xml?? I'm a bit confused here..

Comment: Carrie Fisher was in The Matrix?!  Sure you don't mean Carrie-Anne Moss?!  Not sure the famous bikini would have gone well with the black shades.

Comment: @SirCrispalot no idea maybe you are right..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea is in root element  and then attributes and elements in several repetitive groups:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<movies>
    <movie title="The Matrix" year="1999"/>
        <directors>
            <director>...</director>
            <director>...</director>
            ...
        </directors>
        <stars>
            <star>...</star>
        </stars>
        <writers>
            ...
        </writers>
    </movie>

    <movie title=... year=.../>
        <directors>
            <director>...</director>
            <director>...</director>
            ...
        </directors>
        <stars>
            <star>...</star>
        </stars>
        <writers>
            ...
        </writers>
    </movie>
<movies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the whole thing in some tags and thats XML!

```
<data>
title:The matrix

year: 1999

directors: Andy and Lana Watchowski

writers:Andy and Lana Watchowski

stars: Keanu reeves, carrie fisher

title: star wars

year: 1977

director: George Lucas

writer: George Lucas

stars: mark Hamill, harrison ford
</data>
```

Comment: @SQLhint.com I don't like lazy questions :P